# Button dropdown menu disappears

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I added the following code for my button drop-down for my page http://test.hkkkki.eu/ and here it is the code snippet:

```css
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #ff4e39;
        color: white;
        padding: 0px 16px 0px 6.4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
     font-family: 'Josefin Sans',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color:#fff;
     background-color:#ff4e39;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover { color:#000; transition: all 0.5s ease;}
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #ff4e39;}
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">press</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">priopćenja</a>
        <a href="#">foto</a>
        <a href="#">video</a>
        <a href="#">iz medija</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The result is not good, as the drop-down disappears when trying to pick a sub-menu option. And it is also not on top of the following content. It's probably due to Z-index, but I tried more than a couple of places to put it, and it didn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can see what you mean when I go to [your website](http://test.hkkkki.eu/). I can't see the problem exactly in your code but it seems like the drop down entitled 'press' works fine, are you using the same classes to reference the dropdowns? It would be nice to see the way you created the 'press' dropdown so we can compare and see what went wrong.

Regardless here is the best I can do. [**w3schools** has a very handy tutorial on everything you need to make a hoverable drop down](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp). **Here is a snippet to attempt to answer your question**:

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, check what you changed from that code then you can have an idea of where it went wrong

Comment: I only added a few things (changed font, added a transition, and actually replaced the link names to the ones I need) that should have no effect on the functionality of the code above. This is probably in a collision with some other code on my web (probably the section below the section with buttons), but I can't figure out which :/

Comment: Thanks for changing your code to a snippet, if you run that snippet you can see that the dropdown works. This means that it is something to do with the rest of your code. If you want we can hop in a chat and I can take a look at what is wrong

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to open a chat, but I'm kinda lost, can you open the chat with me? I'll be here waiting...